# Adding subdomain support into lighttpd

Tags: dns, webserver, subdomain, lighttpd

I have a lighttpd server with website placed in */home/httpd/example.com/httpdocs* and there I have a file called *file.php*. When I type *http://en.example.com/file.php* I would like to display *file.php* that is in default website directory (mentioned above).

So I used document-root described here:

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Server.document-rootDetails

in this manner:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "en.example.com/file.php" {
        server.document-root = "/home/httpd/example.com/httpdocs/"
}
```

But unfortunately when I type *http://en.example.com/file.php* into browser I get error 404. What I do wrong and how can I fix it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the example URL *http://en.example.com/file.php*, the host is just *en.example.com* and not *en.example.com/file.php* (*/file.php* is the URL path). So try this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "en.example.com" {
    server.document-root = "/home/httpd/example.com/httpdocs/"
}
```