# lighttpd subdomain without "domain"

Tags: subdomain, lighttpd

Referring to this question here: [Adding subdomain support into lighttpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976628/adding-subdomain-support-into-lighttpd)

I am trying to setup a subdomain on my server. The example provided in the link above works but, the problem is, I still have not bought a domain and, as I am running on a development environment and my IP is dynamic, I have problems in setting it as I need to change the config file every time I change my IP.

Is there any way to set a subdomain without necessarily setting the domain as well?

This question is a good fit for all the people who are running in a development environment with dynamic IP, and need to setup subdomains for their website.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you force the dns (on your local machine) by editing your `/etc/hosts` file ?

```
#[server ip]   [new domain not bought]
90.90.90.90    subdomain.domain.com
```

Then, every time you will go on `subdomain.domain.com`, it will point to `90.90.90.90`, which is your server.